# Drupal 7 skip node in hook after node save

Tags: 7, nodes, hooks

In my custom module I am creating a node using node_save. I have also implemented hook_node_update to catch a user updated node. But every time I call node_save, it also calls my hook. Is there a way I can tell that this update was called using my node_save.
In Drupal 6, I used to add something like $node->skip_it = TRUE in before node_save, and this was available in the update hook. But not any more. Any pointers.

Comment: I don't understand why this `$node->skip_it = TRUE;` wouldn't work in Drupal 7

Answer (score 1):

You can check using below condition while using [node_save](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_save/7)

> If $node->nid is omitted (or $node->is_new is TRUE), a new node will
>   be added.

So, in your hook_node_update check for above condition before executing your code.

Comment: But if I am updating an existing node, then both nid and is_new will not work.

Answer (score 0):

If all the user updates you need to catch happen via the node edit form, you could implement `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()` and append your own submit handler which won't be called on `node_save()`. The downside is that you'll probably need to read any user modifications from `$form_state['values']`.

```
function mymodule_form_MY_CONTENT_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_MY_CONTENT_submit';
}

function mymodule_MY_CONTENT_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  // do stuff here
}
```